# VBA search an array in a column and replace cell value based on value tied to the array

Tags: arrays, vba, replace, match

I created an array for the Number entries (column C) in “Input” and will use it to search in column G of “Destination”.

If there’s a match, replace the row value for “Destination” with value tied to the array in “Input” for their respective columns. For example, I’ll use number 13579  from “Input” and search under column G in “Destination” and when matched, use the Date (column A) and Person (column B) value tied to 13579 in “Input” and replace cell value in “Destination” for the same columns (column B for Date, and column D for Person).

**"Input" worksheet**
[image: Input worksheet]

**"Destination" worksheet**
[image: Destination worksheet (Before and After Changes]

I am new to VBA and tried with my own logic and got an “Object required” error. I marked the section where “Help is needed” (towards end of the code). Thanks!

```
Sub ReplaceValue()

    ' Use entries in Input worksheet as filter criteria for Summary worksheet, copy data to
    ' Destination worksheet and replace cell value based on Input array.

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim srcWS As Worksheet, inputWS As Worksheet, desWS As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Variant, c As Variant
    
    Set srcWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary") ' Thousands of rows
    Set inputWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input")
    Set desWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Destination")
    
    srcWS.AutoFilterMode = False
    
    ' Declare an array to hold filtered criteria
    Dim inputList() As String

    ' Declare a counter for inputList array
    Dim n As Integer

    n = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(inputWS.Range("C:C")) - 2 ' Column has header

    ReDim inputList(n) As String

    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 0 To n
        inputList(i) = inputWS.Range("C" & i + 2)
    Next i
    
    ' Use Input array to filter the Summary worksheet and copy data to the Destination worksheet
    With srcWS.UsedRange
        .AutoFilter 7, inputList(), xlFilterValues
        .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Copy desWS.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        '.AutoFilter
    End With
    
    ' Loop through Input array
    For Each cell In inputList
        If IsError(Application.Match(cell, desWS.Range("G:G"), 0)) Then
            MsgBox (cell & " Not Found")
        Else
            
            ' This is where help is needed. Got "Object required" error.
            For Each c In desWS.Range("G:G")
                desWS.Cells(c.Row, 2).Value2 = inputWS.Cells(cell.Row, 1).Value2 ' Copied Date
                desWS.Cells(c.Row, 4).Value2 = inputWS.Cells(cell.Row, 2).Value2 ' Copied Person
            Next c
        End If
    Next cell
   
        
    srcWS.AutoFilterMode = False
    
    ' Display to user the last row in the Destination worksheet
    desWS.Activate
    Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Select
   
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you looked if any of the variables are nothing? Try using the debugger

Comment: `cell` is an element in an array `InputList` so it doesn't have a Row property. That is the property of a range.

Comment: @Nirostar I'm not familiar with the debugger yet and will require learning on my own. I believe all variables are declared and assigned a value.

Comment: @SJR Thanks for the information on element cell. How can I modify to do what I want?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer in case anyone is interested. I also changed how the array was created. Cheers!

```
Sub ReplaceValue()

   ' Use entries in Input worksheet as filter criteria for Summary worksheet, copy 
   ' data to Destination worksheet and replace cell value based on Input array.

    Dim inputWS As Worksheet, srcWS As Worksheet, desWS As Worksheet
    Dim inputRange As Range, srcRange As Range, cell As Range, c As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim inputList As Variant
    
    Set srcWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary")
    Set inputWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input")
    Set desWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Destination")
    
    With inputWS
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
        Set inputRange = .Range("C2:C" & lastRow)
    End With
    
    ' Used to transpose as autofilter criteria
    inputList = inputRange.Value

    With srcWS
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
        Set srcRange = .Range("G2:G" & lastRow)
    End With
      
    ' Filter input criteria in Summary worksheet and copy to Destination worksheet
    With srcWS.UsedRange
        .AutoFilter 7, Application.Transpose(inputList), xlFilterValues
        .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Copy desWS.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        '.AutoFilter
    End With
    
    For Each cell In inputRange
        If IsError(Application.Match(cell, desWS.Range("G:G"), 0)) Then
            MsgBox (cell & " Not Found")
        Else
            For Each c In desWS.Range("G:G")
                If cell.Value = c.Value Then
                    desWS.Cells(c.Row, 2).Value = inputWS.Cells(cell.Row, 1).Value ' Replaced Date
                    desWS.Cells(c.Row, 4).Value = inputWS.Cells(cell.Row, 2).Value ' Replaced Person
                End If
            Next c
        End If
    Next cell

    srcWS.AutoFilterMode = False

    desWS.Activate
    Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Select
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

You want to loop through the Cells :

```
For Each c In desWS.Range("G:G").Cells
```

Comment: You don't need to specify `Cells`, it is implied, and this would not cause the error caused by the OP.

Comment: @SJR darn, you're right! I'd actually tried it quickly and got the error without the `.Cells`, but it must have been something else. My bad.

Comment: Arguably it's good practice to do what you've done, particularly as OP has declared `c` as Variant not Range.